# The continuity of a function of two variables

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

How can I demonstrate the continuity of this function. If $a>0$, 
\begin{align}
    f(x,y) = 
        \left\{ \begin{array}{lll}
            \dfrac{x^3y}{ax^4+y^4} & \text{if} & (x,y) \ne (0,0) \\
            0                     & \text{if} & (x,y) =   (0,0)
        \end{array} \right.
\end{align}

I suppose I'm gonna have to calculate the limit of the function when $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$. But I don't understand what that's gonna bring to my proof.

How can I continue my proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :**

Approach to the point $(0,0)$ along the path $y=mx$.

Which shows that $f$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Showing discontinuity at (0,0).............

Comment: Can you show how to calculate this limit? I suppose
$$lim \frac{x^3(mx)}{ax^4+(mx)^4}=\frac{mx^4}{ax^4+m^4x^4}=\frac{m}{a+m}$$.

Comment: That limit depends on $m$ ..and so $f$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$

Comment: Do you know the basic definition of continuity & discontinuity of function of several variable ?

Comment: Not really. I supposed that is the same way of a function of one variable?

Comment: Read your basic calculus book first and then question here..